# How to generate a sentence from feature vector or words?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, word2vec, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I used VGG 16-Layer Caffe model for image captions and I have several captions per image. Now, I want to generate a sentence from those captions (words).
I read in a paper on LSTM that I should remove the SoftMax layer from the training network and provide the 4096 feature vector from `fc7` layer directly to LSTM.
I am new to LSTM and RNN stuff.
Where should I begin? Is there any tutorial showing how to generate sentence by sequence labeling?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK the master branch of BVLC/caffe does not yet support a recurrent layer architecture.

You should pull branch `recurrent` from [jeffdonahue/caffe](https://github.com/jeffdonahue/caffe/tree/recurrent). This branch supports RNN and LSTM.
It also contains a detailed [example](https://github.com/jeffdonahue/caffe/tree/recurrent/examples/coco_caption) on how to generate image captions trained using [MS COCO](http://mscoco.org/) data.