# How do I use 4096D vector as input to LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, lstm, pycaffe

I am trying to build a Deep Learning system that generates a sentence description for a image. For this I have used a trained CNN caffe model to get a 4096 dimensional feature vector. From what I understand, I need to give this 4096 dimensional vector as an input to LSTM. How can this be done in caffe or some other framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a sentence from feature vector or words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494796/how-to-generate-a-sentence-from-feature-vector-or-words)

Comment: Can you please elaborate the process?

Comment: Training LSTM model for predicting a sentence given an input image is too long for the scope of SO answer/thread. please see the examples in the `recurrent` branch of caffe. Especially the `coco_example`.

Comment: You can get exact pointers from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34494925/1714410) linked by the dup question.